# serving laravel with apache vhost

Tags: apache, laravel

I followed instructions and added in my httpd-vhost.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName project-laravel-learn.my
DocumentRoot "/srv/http/project-laravel-learn.my/public/"
</VirtualHost>
```

also added like for other local projects, map in hosts file so that 
project-laravel-learn.my goes resolves to 127.0.0.1

http (web user), has all permissions to write and read on that `public`
folder,
also `app/storage` is `rw-` for http, 
however, when I visit project-laravel-learn.my I get page saying

Whoops, looks like something went wrong!

What might be the problem? Also how I can get more detailed error message as
this one above isn't that much useful.

Just to add, app was working fine before I moved it to /srv/http/, while developing and using `php artisan serve` command.

EDIT: Ok it works, I forgot to start my local web server instance, however now routing does not work, I get only homepage, but clicking on any link gives 404 object not found error!?

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution here..

http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working

I will leave it for a future reference.